# It's possible to change the templateURL through attributes in a angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes

I have the following directive:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';
  function header() {
    return {
      templateUrl: '/app/home/homeheader.html'
    };
  }
   angular.module('app').directive('appheader', header);
})();
```

Due to I need to change the header depending of the page what used it, I guess if I can do in the DOM something like this:

index.html

```
 <appheader page="index"></appheader>
```

signUp.html

```
 <appheader page="signUp"></appheader>
```

...

Then in the directive, assign the template that I want.

I've reading some on the web but I did not found any solution. There are so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function into `templateUrl`, check the `page` attribute and let your imagination go wild!

Take a look at the [Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) documentation.

Heres an example to get you started:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  function header() {
    return {
      templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {

        // check the attribute value
        if (attrs.page === "home") {
          return '/app/home/homeheader.html';
        } else {
          return '/app/home/signupheader.html';
        }

        // OR use the attribute value as part of the template
        return '/app/home/' + attrs.page + 'header.html';

      }
    };
  }

  angular.module('app').directive('appheader', header);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`templateUrl` can be a function.

The example given in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is like this:

`angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
      return 'customer-' + attr.type + '.html';
    }
  };
});`